# Find $X$ so that $MX^\top$ is ortho-projector onto $\mathrm{span}(M)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, projection-matrices

Given a matrix $M\in\Bbb R^{n\times m}$ with $n>m$.

What is the fastes way to see (and shortest to write down) that there exists a matrix $X\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ so that $M X^\top$ is th ortho-projector onto $\mathrm{span}(M)$.

I know how to do it if $M$ is of full column-rank. Then the columns of $M$ are a basis of $\mathrm{span}(M)$ and we choose the columns of $X$ as the dual basis. But what if $\mathrm{rank}(M)<m\,$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take $X^T=M^+$, the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $M$.